# Associating a renamed executable with our application fails on command line in Windows

Tags: windows, command-line, file-association

This is on Windows 7.

We've got a program we install that we've associated with extension .xyz. Our '.xyz' files are actually executable files (originally .exe)

If you double-click the renamed .xyz file, it will be opened using our application as expected.

From cmd.exe, if you just 'run' the .xyz file, "C:>myfile.xyz", Windows will just run the myfile.xyz as if it were an executable file (which it is). Is there any way we can modify our .xyz file to get around this or a registry flag that can be set to prevent this behavior just for .xyz files?

Comment: I'm afraid you cannot do that. Why not just start it with your application directly: your_application.exe myfile.xyz

Comment: Yeah, that's the other option. I didn't like it because we install to different locations for different users (don't ask...) so it's hard to make a one-size-fits-all script but it's not the end of the world.

Answer (score 0):

Do the .xyz files have to be executable, or can you modify them into something else yet retain the information (e.g. gzip them or just modify a few key bytes)?  If you could do that, and then your application could undo it, I would think you could make your scheme work.